# solr - set fileds as default search field

Tags: solr, solr4

The following query works well for me

```
http://[]:8983/solr/vault/select?q=VersionComments%3AWhite
```

returns all the documents where version comments includes White

I try to omit the field name and put it as a default value as follows : 
In solr config I write

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
  -->
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">PackageName</str>
   <str name="df">Tag</str>
   <str name="df">VersionComments</str>
   <str name="df">VersionTag</str>
   <str name="df">Description</str>
   <str name="df">SKU</str>
   <str name="df">SKUDesc</str>
 </lst>
```

I restart the solr and create a full import.
Then I try using

```
 http://[]:8983/solr/vault/select?q=White
```

(Where

```
 http://[]:8983/solr/vault/select?q=VersionComments%3AWhite
```

still works)

But I dont get the document any as answer.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Re-Opening [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941259/solr-set-fileds-as-default-search-field-using-edismax) using edismax parser

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know you should only have the `<str name="df"></str>` declared once in your `requestHandler`

Typically what I do is copy all the fields that i want to search into a default search field called `text`.

schema.xml:

```
<copyField source="name_t" dest="text"/>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
-->
<lst name="defaults">
   <str name="q">*:*</str>
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">text</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

If this is not good enough, you can always search other fields using a `dismax` search with the `qf` declaration like so:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/vault/select/?q= White&defType=dismax&qf=PackageName+Tag+VersionComments+VersionTag+Description+SKU+SKUDesc`

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. 1. Should I use dismax or edismax? 2. Why should I use copy field?

Comment: I use edismax, that is the new standard for dismax searches; but that is really up to you. Using copyFields allows you to search one field over many, speeding up your search.