# Solr 5.3 implementation processes docs but doesn't return results

Tags: indexing, solr, full-text-search, dataimporthandler

I have recently set up a local instance of Solr 5.3 in an effort to get it going for my company. As an initial test case I've set up a Data Import Handler (DIH) that returns PDFs stored within a file directory. When I execute the full import in the admin tool, the DIH processes all the files within the directory, and I'm able to run a general query (*:*) which returns all indexed fields for every record in the index.

When I switch to a specific query using a word definitely contained within the files, however, Solr returns no results. What connection am I not making here?

I can provide excerpts from the schema, solrconfig, and custom data config if needed, but I don't want to oversaturate this post.

Comment: you can determine the index of success yet ?  if index success finished , how manys documents in index ?

Comment: @QinDongLiang, executing the DIH works with no problem. Letting it run on my directory gets all documents expected. What I *did* find just now is that prefixing the query with the field name and a colon does return results. This isn't what I was expecting; I thought that's what the fl field in the admin tool is for.

Comment: That should be df field, not fl field. I'm learning as I go!

Answer (score 0):

The answer I came up with involved a simple newbie mistake combined with something I wasn't anticipating.

1) First, I didn't have my field set to `indexed="true"`. I set that. Yeesh, it stinks being new to this!

2) I needed to make a change to solrconfig.xml for the core in question. Thanks to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927992/solr-set-fileds-as-default-search-field), I was able to determine that I needed to add a default field in the /select requestHandler. Uncommenting the relevant line in solrconfig and changing the field name did the trick-- I no longer need to supply the name in df to return results.

My carryover question for anyone coming across this question in the future is whether this latter point is the proper way to go about using default fields. I see in schema.xml that  is deprecated (or heading that direction) in 5.3.0. So is it alright to define df in solrconfig instead?